# How do I detect in the Windows Registry if a user has Crystal Reports installed

Tags: crystal-reports, inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup to create an installer and I am unable to tell whether a user has installed the CR. I'm looking like this:

```
[Code]
//Check for Crystal Reports
function CheckForCrystalReports: Boolean;
var
  regresult: Cardinal;
begin
  RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Installer\CRV','Install',regresult);
  Result := regresult = 0;
end;

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\CRViewer.exe"; Parameters: "q:a /c:""C:\Users\paulo.romeiro\Desktop\New folder\Crystal Reports 2010""install /l /q"""; Check: CheckForCrystalReports; StatusMsg: Instalando o Crystal Reports Viewer
```

thanks!!

Comment: Substituindo o 

RegQueryDWordValue
por

RegQueryStringValue
E fazendo as devidas adaptações,

consegui identificar se o CR Viewer está instalado ou não pois o mesmo só usa chaves REG_SZ.

Obrigado.

Comment: Sorry, in English please.

Comment: No worries :) Anyway, you can post and accept your solution as an answer.